# Reduce a function on a grouped column in mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a function which finds a sort of intersection of two strings of prose:

```
# Function to get intersection of words
str_intersect_by_word_list <- function(string1, string2){
  map2_chr(str_split(string1, '\\s'), str_split(string2, '\\s'), 
           ~str_c(intersect(.x, .y), collapse = " "))
}
```

and a table with strings to match on:

```
# Sample data
my_df <- tibble(
  grp = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 3),
  strng = c(
    "Hi I'm Abe",
    "Hi I'm Beau",
    "Hi I'm Cat",
    "Hi there I'm Doug",
    "Hi there I'm Emily",
    "Hi there I'm Finn",
    "Hi it's nice to be here",
    "Hi it's nice to meet you",
    "Hi it's nice outside"
  )
)
```

If I want to create a column with the common string, I can do so like this:

```
# This works as expected
my_df %>% 
  mutate(
    common_string = my_df %>% 
      pull(strng) %>% 
      reduce(str_intersect_by_word_list)
  )
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  grp   strng                    common_string
  <chr> <chr>                    <chr>        
1 A     Hi I'm Abe               Hi           
2 A     Hi I'm Beau              Hi           
3 A     Hi I'm Cat               Hi           
4 B     Hi there I'm Doug        Hi           
5 B     Hi there I'm Emily       Hi           
6 B     Hi there I'm Finn        Hi           
7 C     Hi it's nice to be here  Hi           
8 C     Hi it's nice to meet you Hi           
9 C     Hi it's nice outside     Hi
```

I would like to create a column with the string that is common to each group.  However, inside the grouping, I can only access either the entire columns worth of `strng`, which gives the same output as above, or the current value of `strng`, which causes an error since my function `str_intersect_by_word_list` expects two inputs.

I tried referencing `cur_data_all`, but I don't think this is how that function was intended to be used, and it gives me the same results as above anyway.

```
# This fails.
my_df %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  mutate(
    grp_string = cur_data_all() %>% 
      pull(strng) %>% 
      reduce(str_intersect_by_word_list)
  )
```

The expected output would be

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  grp   strng                    grp_string
  <chr> <chr>                    <chr>        
1 A     Hi I'm Abe               Hi I'm           
2 A     Hi I'm Beau              Hi I'm          
3 A     Hi I'm Cat               Hi I'm          
4 B     Hi there I'm Doug        Hi there I'm         
5 B     Hi there I'm Emily       Hi there I'm         
6 B     Hi there I'm Finn        Hi there I'm         
7 C     Hi it's nice to be here  Hi it's nice          
8 C     Hi it's nice to meet you Hi it's nice          
9 C     Hi it's nice outside     Hi it's nice
```

How can I get the common words from each group?

Comment: It seems that your `group_by(grp)` is actually an *anti-grouping*, where the `A`s are not processed together. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi @r2evans, I think it's just a small slip by Rob when manually typing the example.  **Edit**: it has now been fixed.

Comment: I created my example wrong.  @r2evans is right.  I've fixed it. It looks like akrun's solution will work.

Comment: Hey Rob, thanks for updating the sample output!  Just FYI: in the code that generates your sample data, the column `grp = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 3)` still needs to be updated, to something like `grp = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 3)`.

Comment: In this case, @akrun's proposed (and now deleted) solution should solve your problem.

Comment: (though I think I'd remove the embedded `%>%` and just go with `grp_string = reduce(strng, str_intersect_by_word_list)`.)

Comment: @r2evans That's definitely cleaner, and closer to what I was initially trying (`grp_string = reduce(str_intersect_by_word_list(strng))`). Thank you.

Comment: Btw: you could use `rep(LETTERS[1:3], each=3)`.

Comment: Hey Rob!  As it turns out, your original attempt was actually **correct**.  Your omission of `each = 3` in `rep()` was singlehandedly responsible for messing up your sample data, which in turn was singlehandedly responsible for grouping together the wrong rows.  Once the wrong rows were grouped together (`"Hi I'm Abe"` with `"Hi there I'm Doug"` and `"Hi it's nice to be here"`) the only string they had in common was `"Hi"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TLDR

Your workflow seems fine! Your **sample data** is responsible for the bad results. Use my [original suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68353009/reduce-a-function-on-a-grouped-column-in-mutate#comment120803319_68353009) (approved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/5197103)) to generate the correct sample data via `grp = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 3)`.

## What Went Wrong

When generating your sample data

```
# Sample data
my_df <- tibble(
  grp = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 3),
  strng = c(
    "Hi I'm Abe",
    "Hi I'm Beau",
    "Hi I'm Cat",
    "Hi there I'm Doug",
    "Hi there I'm Emily",
    "Hi there I'm Finn",
    "Hi it's nice to be here",
    "Hi it's nice to meet you",
    "Hi it's nice outside"
  )
)
```

you incorrectly used `rep(LETTERS[1:3], 3)`, which takes the *entire* vector `c("A", "B", "C")` and repeats it `3` times:

```
#   1     2     3
# |---| |---| |---|
  A B C A B C A B C
```

The result is an **incorrect `grp` column** in `my_df`

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  grp   strng                   
  <chr> <chr>                   
1 A     Hi I'm Abe              
2 B     Hi I'm Beau             
3 C     Hi I'm Cat              
4 A     Hi there I'm Doug       
5 B     Hi there I'm Emily      
6 C     Hi there I'm Finn       
7 A     Hi it's nice to be here 
8 B     Hi it's nice to meet you
9 C     Hi it's nice outside
```

Now, even a perfect workflow will give you undesired results. When grouping by `grp`, here is group `"A"`:

```
  grp   strng                  
  <chr> <chr>                  
1 A     Hi I'm Abe             
4 A     Hi there I'm Doug      
7 A     Hi it's nice to be here
```

Naturally, the only thing these `strng`s have in common — their only "intersection" — is the prefix `"Hi"`.

```
  grp   strng                   grp_string
  <chr> <chr>                   <chr>     
1 A     Hi I'm Abe              Hi        
4 A     Hi there I'm Doug       Hi        
7 A     Hi it's nice to be here Hi
```

Since the same goes for the other groups `"B"` and `"C"`, then — **by sheer coincidence** — each group happens to **independently** have `"Hi"` as its "intersection".  The result is a `grp_string` column populated exclusively by `"Hi"`, whose (grouped) results

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   grp [3]
  grp   strng                    grp_string
  <chr> <chr>                    <chr>     
1 A     Hi I'm Abe               Hi        
2 B     Hi I'm Beau              Hi        
3 C     Hi I'm Cat               Hi        
4 A     Hi there I'm Doug        Hi        
5 B     Hi there I'm Emily       Hi        
6 C     Hi there I'm Finn        Hi        
7 A     Hi it's nice to be here  Hi        
8 B     Hi it's nice to meet you Hi        
9 C     Hi it's nice outside     Hi
```

look identical to the (ungrouped) results of your ungrouped attempt:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  grp   strng                    grp_string
  <chr> <chr>                    <chr>     
1 A     Hi I'm Abe               Hi        
2 B     Hi I'm Beau              Hi        
3 C     Hi I'm Cat               Hi        
4 A     Hi there I'm Doug        Hi        
5 B     Hi there I'm Emily       Hi        
6 C     Hi there I'm Finn        Hi        
7 A     Hi it's nice to be here  Hi        
8 B     Hi it's nice to meet you Hi        
9 C     Hi it's nice outside     Hi
```

## How to Fix It

Instead of using `rep(LETTERS[1:3], 3)`, you should use `rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 3)`, which repeats *each element* in the vector `3` times:

```
# 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
  A A A B B B C C C
```

By correcting this one oversight when generating `my_df`

```
# Sample data
my_df <- tibble(
  grp = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 3),
  #                       ^^^^^^^^
  strng = c(
    "Hi I'm Abe",
    "Hi I'm Beau",
    "Hi I'm Cat",
    "Hi there I'm Doug",
    "Hi there I'm Emily",
    "Hi there I'm Finn",
    "Hi it's nice to be here",
    "Hi it's nice to meet you",
    "Hi it's nice outside"
  )
)
```

you will produce the **correct `grp` column** in `my_df`:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  grp   strng                   
  <chr> <chr>                   
1 A     Hi I'm Abe              
2 A     Hi I'm Beau             
3 A     Hi I'm Cat              
4 B     Hi there I'm Doug       
5 B     Hi there I'm Emily      
6 B     Hi there I'm Finn       
7 C     Hi it's nice to be here 
8 C     Hi it's nice to meet you
9 C     Hi it's nice outside
```

and your **original code**

```
# Function to get intersection of words
str_intersect_by_word_list <- function(string1, string2){
  map2_chr(str_split(string1, '\\s'), str_split(string2, '\\s'), 
           ~str_c(intersect(.x, .y), collapse = " "))
} 

# ...

my_df %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  mutate(
    grp_string = cur_data_all() %>% 
      pull(strng) %>% 
      reduce(str_intersect_by_word_list)
  )
```

**will** produce your intended results:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   grp [3]
  grp   strng                    grp_string  
  <chr> <chr>                    <chr>       
1 A     Hi I'm Abe               Hi I'm      
2 A     Hi I'm Beau              Hi I'm      
3 A     Hi I'm Cat               Hi I'm      
4 B     Hi there I'm Doug        Hi there I'm
5 B     Hi there I'm Emily       Hi there I'm
6 B     Hi there I'm Finn        Hi there I'm
7 C     Hi it's nice to be here  Hi it's nice
8 C     Hi it's nice to meet you Hi it's nice
9 C     Hi it's nice outside     Hi it's nice
```

## Note

While your workflow does work here, it's certainly worth exploring the alternatives by [Onyambu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68353761) or [Ian Gow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68353231), which might prove cleaner, more efficient, or more extensible.

Answer (score 3):

Please consider doing:

```
my_df %>%
   group_by(grp) %>%
   mutate(common_string = str_c(reduce(str_split(strng, "\\s+"), intersect),collapse = ' '))

# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   grp [3]
  grp   strng                    common_string
  <chr> <chr>                    <chr>        
1 A     Hi I'm Abe               Hi I'm       
2 A     Hi I'm Beau              Hi I'm       
3 A     Hi I'm Cat               Hi I'm       
4 B     Hi there I'm Doug        Hi there I'm 
5 B     Hi there I'm Emily       Hi there I'm 
6 B     Hi there I'm Finn        Hi there I'm 
7 C     Hi it's nice to be here  Hi it's nice 
8 C     Hi it's nice to meet you Hi it's nice 
9 C     Hi it's nice outside     Hi it's nice
```

Comment: Hello!  There was some confusion here before you arrived, since Rob's **sample data** was incorrect, so it gave Rob the wrong results.  Once I tested Rob's workflow with `str_intersect_by_word_list()`, on the _correct_ sample data, it gave the intended results.

Answer (score 2):

I mostly just rearranged code from the original question and borrowed a suggestion from @Martin Gal regarding `rep`.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

# Function to get intersection of words
str_intersect_by_word_list <- function(string1, string2){
  purrr::map2_chr(stringr::str_split(string1, '\\s'), 
                  stringr::str_split(string2, '\\s'), 
           ~stringr::str_c(intersect(.x, .y), collapse = " "))
} 

# Sample data
my_df <- tibble(
    grp = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 3),
    strng = c(
      "Hi I'm Abe",
      "Hi I'm Beau",
      "Hi I'm Cat",
      "Hi there I'm Doug",
      "Hi there I'm Emily",
      "Hi there I'm Finn",
      "Hi it's nice to be here",
      "Hi it's nice to meet you",
      "Hi it's nice outside"
    )
  )

my_df %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  mutate(grp_string = purrr::reduce(strng, str_intersect_by_word_list))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#> # Groups:   grp [3]
#>   grp   strng                    grp_string  
#>   <chr> <chr>                    <chr>       
#> 1 A     Hi I'm Abe               Hi I'm      
#> 2 A     Hi I'm Beau              Hi I'm      
#> 3 A     Hi I'm Cat               Hi I'm      
#> 4 B     Hi there I'm Doug        Hi there I'm
#> 5 B     Hi there I'm Emily       Hi there I'm
#> 6 B     Hi there I'm Finn        Hi there I'm
#> 7 C     Hi it's nice to be here  Hi it's nice
#> 8 C     Hi it's nice to meet you Hi it's nice
#> 9 C     Hi it's nice outside     Hi it's nice
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

And here's a variant that puts all the details in a single function:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

# Function to get intersection of words
str_intersect <- function(str_vec) {
  
  str_intersect_by_word_list <- function(string1, string2){
    purrr::map2_chr(stringr::str_split(string1, '\\s'), 
                    stringr::str_split(string2, '\\s'), 
                    ~stringr::str_c(intersect(.x, .y), collapse = " "))
  } 
  purrr::reduce(str_vec, str_intersect_by_word_list)
}

# Sample data
my_df <- tibble(
    grp = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 3),
    strng = c(
      "Hi I'm Abe",
      "Hi I'm Beau",
      "Hi I'm Cat",
      "Hi there I'm Doug",
      "Hi there I'm Emily",
      "Hi there I'm Finn",
      "Hi it's nice to be here",
      "Hi it's nice to meet you",
      "Hi it's nice outside"
    )
  )

my_df %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  mutate(grp_string = str_intersect(strng))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#> # Groups:   grp [3]
#>   grp   strng                    grp_string  
#>   <chr> <chr>                    <chr>       
#> 1 A     Hi I'm Abe               Hi I'm      
#> 2 A     Hi I'm Beau              Hi I'm      
#> 3 A     Hi I'm Cat               Hi I'm      
#> 4 B     Hi there I'm Doug        Hi there I'm
#> 5 B     Hi there I'm Emily       Hi there I'm
#> 6 B     Hi there I'm Finn        Hi there I'm
#> 7 C     Hi it's nice to be here  Hi it's nice
#> 8 C     Hi it's nice to meet you Hi it's nice
#> 9 C     Hi it's nice outside     Hi it's nice
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>